# How to use $(this) to select an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code, which animates an image to spin 3 times on it's axis using CSS3:

```
$(function(){
    var $img = $(".flipimg");

    function rotate(degree,speed,orientation) {

    $img.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotateY('+degree+'deg)'});
    $img.css({ '-o-transform': 'rotateY('+degree+'deg)'});
    $img.css({ '-transform': 'rotateY('+degree+'deg)'});
    $img.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotateY('+degree+'deg)'});

    $img.css({ '-moz-transition': speed+'s'});
    $img.css({ '-moz-transform-style': 'preserve-3d'});
    $img.css({ '-webkit-transition': speed+'s'});
    $img.css({ '-webkit-transform-style': 'preserve-3d'});
    $img.css({ '-o-transition': speed+'s'});
    $img.css({ '-o-transition-style': 'preserve-3d'});
    $img.css({ '-transition': speed+'s'});
    $img.css({ '-transform-style': 'preserve-3d'});

    }
    $('.flipimg').click(function(){

        $speed = 1;
        for($i=0;$i<=1080;$i++)
        {
            if($i % 100 == 0)
            {
                 $speed = $speed + 0.2 ;
            }
            rotate($i,$speed,'Y');
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.flipimg').removeAttr('style');
        },3000);

    });

});
```

At the moment, it applies to all images with the .flipimg class. I want to update this code so that the effect only applies to the specific image that was clicked. I assume I should use the $(this) string, but am not sure how or where the correct usage would be?

Comment: no need to call `css()` a dozen times, combine all the properties into one object and call it once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var $img = $(".flipimg");

    function rotate(degree, speed, orientation, s) {

        s.css({
            WebkitTransform: 'rotateY(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotateY(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-transform': 'rotateY(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-moz-transition': speed + 's',
            '-moz-transform-style': 'preserve-3d',
            '-webkit-transition': speed + 's',
            '-webkit-transform-style': 'preserve-3d',
            '-o-transition': speed + 's',
            '-o-transition-style': 'preserve-3d',
            '-transition': speed + 's',
            '-transform-style': 'preserve-3d'
        });

    }
    $img.click(function() {
        var _this = $(this);

        $speed = 1;
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 1080; $i++) {
            if ($i % 100 == 0) {
                $speed = $speed + 0.2;
            }
            rotate($i, $speed, 'Y', _this);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            _this.removeAttr('style');
        }, 3000);

    });

});
```

Comment: no @Aperçu, I'm passing the jQuery instance to the rotate function as parameter

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is to use css animate instead and then listen for the animation end event. This way u can use a css class to start the animation and remove it when it's done. And I only do it on the image that is clicked using this as u requested.

My css:

```
.image {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin:10 px;
}
.spin{
    -webkit-animation:spin 1s linear 3;
    -moz-animation:spin 1s linear 3;
    animation:spin 1s linear 3;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

And this small javascript:

```
(function($){
var animEndEventNames = ['webkitAnimationEnd',
        'oAnimationEnd',
        'MSAnimationEnd',
        'animationend'].join(" ");

    $(".image").click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass("spin").on(animEndEventNames, function(e){
            $this.off(animEndEventNames).removeClass("spin");
        });

    });    
}(jQuery));
```

U can test it out in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aZYY2/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to not save all images to $img variable at top and pass in $(this) to rotate as another parameter on click event like so:

```
$('.flipimg').on('click', function () {
    rotate( $(this), $i, $speed, Y );
});
```

And update rotate to take this parameters and use it instead of $img